# Will the react component be rendered twice if parent and child components use useSelector hook for the same data?

Tags: reactjs, performance, optimization, react-redux

I want to know in the case shown below (parent and child components are accessing the same data) will the child component be rendered twice since `useSelector` hook re-renders a component on every change of a state.

```
function Parent() {
  const data = useSelector(state => state.data);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {data}
      </div>
      <Child/>
    </div>
  )
}

function Child() {
  const data = useSelector(state => state.data);
  return (
    <div>
      {data}
    </div> 
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[React Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) uses [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) in it's [source code](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/components/connectAdvanced.js#L474), so the child component will not be rendered twice, since `React.memo` prevents unnecessary renderings.